# Django - before doing the CRUD in the ORM

Tags: django

Is it possible in Django or has it been done?

That before you do save an operation reagarding CRUD, there should be a permission first in the admin? Let us say, After I created an object from a form there should be a part where an admin interface in another browser will tick or check this operation before it is executed. I can explain more if needed

Comment: sounds like you want something like this https://github.com/dominno/django-moderation or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-werewolf/0.4.2  ...there are probably many others

Comment: I'm current using the django-moderation have you tried it yourself on your end?

Comment: no I haven't used it

Comment: Well anyway django-moderation somehow works for me thanks!